# Wordpress Bootstrap Handburger Menu Wont Open

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress-theming

I have been in the process of working on a Worpress Bootstrap theme (my editing temporary domain is https://inedited-remains.000webhostapp.com), but I have come across a problem that I can't seem to solve. I've tried everything I know how to do, and searched the forums of the theme template, and here on StackOverflow, but can't seem to figure out.
I have reset the theme and reinstalled it, that's why all the fonts are bland, but I'm mainly concerned with the nav menu at this point. 
The template has a responsive nav menu that becomes a hamburger when the screen reaches below a certain point.

```html
<html lang="en-GB" class="gr__inedited-remains_000webhostapp_com">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href="https://inedited-remains.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/themes/greatmag/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=1" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="greatmag-style-css" href="https://inedited-remains.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/themes/greatmag/style.css?ver=5.1.1" type="text/css" media="all">

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default main-navigation bgf6">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-8 active"><a title="Home" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9"><a title="Bladesmithing Courses" href="/courses">Bladesmithing Courses</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10"><a title="Location" href="/location">Location</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a title="Accommodation" href="/accommodation">Accommodation</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12"><a title="Contact Us" href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <button class="off-canvas-trigger" aria-controls="primary" aria-expanded="false"> ----
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <body>
    <div>
      <row class="container">
        Hello... Blablabla... Thanks</row>
    </div>
  </body>
```

As you can see in the snippet, it doesnt open anything when you click the menu, same as on the website.
It might be something to do with the CSS, but I am truly at a loss.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if I´m not wrong you need to reference the js of the booststrap version you are using at the end of the body to make it work, i had a similar problem with a hamburguer menu and I solved it just by settint the js refs at the end of the body

Comment: also be sure that the version of the boostrapt you are using is the same of the version of boostrap js libraries you are using.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds promising. I will try this out. 
Thanks.